# onclick within a collection map in Astro

Tags: javascript, astrojs

New to Astro, trying to get a function bound to an element rendered for each image I have in a collection of images (making a gallery interface where you can click an image, and make it full screen).

```
{images.map(img => (
    <li class="tile h-48 flex-shrink-0">
        <img class="h-full transition-transform hover:scale-105 cursor-pointer" src={`/assets/${img}`}/>
    </li>
))}
```

Can render the HTML fine, but struggling getting my head around adding an `onclick` to this?

Have tried `<script>` but that's processed by astro. Added the `is:inline` attribute, but that still didn't register the function definition, or run anything once I'd added the `onclick=myFcn()`

The [docs](https://%7Bp.images.map(img%20=%3E%20(%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%20class=%22tile%20h-48%20flex-shrink-0%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cimg%20class=%22h-full%20transition-transform%20hover:scale-105%20cursor-pointer%22%20src=%7B%60/assets/3d/$%7Bp.path%7D/$%7Bimg%7D%60%7D/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/li%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20))%7D) mention examples of binding a function to multiple of the same element, but no example on how I can still get access to the mapped data from my data collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For collection map this can be achieved by `data-*` attribute.

In my example I was trying to switch between themes, so my implementation is as follow

`ThemeSwitcher.astro`

```
---
const themes = [
    { key: "light", value: " light" },
    { key: "dark", value: " dark" },
    { key: "cupcake", value: " cupcake" },
];
---

<details class="dropdown dropdown-end">
    <summary class="m-1 btn">Theme</summary>
    <ul class="p-2 shadow menu dropdown-content bg-base-200 rounded-box w-52">
        {
            themes.map((theme) => (
                <>
                    <li>
                        <button
                            data-set-theme={theme.key}
                            class=""
                        >
                            {theme.value}
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
</details>

<script>
    // set initial theme from local storage
    const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
    const html = document.querySelector("html") as HTMLElement;
    html.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);

    const btns = document.querySelectorAll(
        "[data-set-theme]"
    ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;

    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const theme = btn.getAttribute("data-set-theme") as string;
            localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
            html.setAttribute("data-theme", theme);
            btns.forEach((otherBtn) => {
                if (otherBtn !== btn) {
                    otherBtn.classList.remove("active");
                }
            });
            btn.classList.add("active");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to call a function that we receive in props?